# Not receiving any reputation from my answer being upvoted

Tags: support

This has happened to me before, but I never reported it, because I was busy, but now it felt like a good time. I'm attaching a screenshot, which you can also see in [full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y50I.png).

As you can see, my answer has been up-voted 4 times, but I have received 0 reputation for it. I know my reputation was 6062 before I posted the answer and it's still the same.

I don't know where else to report this bug. I hope this is the right place.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a daily limit of 200 for upvotes, you must have hit it. Your daily reputation is shown as 199, and you had a single -1 for antonym of holster. You won't get any more rep for upvotes today, but you can still earn rep from accepting answers, having your answers accepted and from bounties.

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> - A maximum of +200 reputation may be earned per day. Accepted answers are immune to this cap ([source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/daily-dose-of-daily-reputation-ca/)), as are bounties ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483019/how-does-the-bounty-system-work-in-stackoverflow)). (For the purposes of this calcuation, new days start at 00:00 UTC ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)).